# How can I get access to elements created with NgFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

Morning all. I've asked this one before with no answer but my question was badly phrased so [I've put together a plunk that will hopefully show what I'm doing](http://plnkr.co/edit/jcdQDpk9cz9Z9W9sDRT2?p=preview)

As simply as I can - I have a `Service` that provides a list of names and tracks which is currently selected. It also has methods for changing this selection and a `BehaviourSubject` that notifies when a change has occurred. The currently selected name is displayed in the main app.

The full list of names is displayed by a `Component` and another `Component` provides UI for changing the selected name.

When the selection changes, this is reflected both in the main app and by the position of the `ListComponent` which will always have the selected name aligned with the left of the screen.

My question is about the methods I use in positioning and styling the `ListComp`. These are in `src/list.com.ts` at line 40 onwards in [my plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jcdQDpk9cz9Z9W9sDRT2?p=preview).

When the component receives notice that the selected item has changed I need to get a reference to the specific HTMLElement that was created by `ngFor` based on that data item. I then need to apply a style to the selected element and move the container so that it lines up with the rest of my layout.

The positioning part *works* as you can see using `getElementById()` but is there a more *Angular* way it could be done?

I am then completely unsure about the best way to apply a `selected` style to the currently selected element. Any and all advice is good here!

I really hope this makes sense. I've spent way too long on the original build and now on plnkr and SO and I hope I'm just missing the wood for the trees (or something).

Please shout out if I can clarify anything in my explanation.

Thank you all so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not fully understand your problem but I would suggest an approach where you don't need access to the element but instead update the model and let Angular do the DOM modification:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let item of listService.listData" class="cell" id="cell-{{item}}" 
    [class.selected]="item == selected">{{item}}</div>
```

```ts
  constructor(private listService:ListService){
accordingly
    listService.nameSelection.subscribe(name => {
      this.selected = name;
    });
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wvTnr16CQsgX8uRGEbyW?p=preview)

Comment: I like this approach and it indeed works so I'm bestowing **The Tick**. Annoyingly while this works in my example when I try it in my actual build (vastly more complex) I get another error -  **`Expression has changed after it was checked`**. Don't suppose you can shed any light on that? If not I'll probably be back here with another question as soon as I work out what the actual problem is. Cheers anyway

Comment: If this is because you change model (properties bound to by the view) data inside `ngOnChanges()`, `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()` or similar, then inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` after the modification. If not, then please create a new question.